# Should I have to take a technical test for a change of position at my company of 4+ years?

Tags: interviewing

I've been at my current company for just under four and a half years, working as a front-end web developer. I've recently applied for a new position within the company, essentially doing more "interactive" front-end development for a different part of the business. I haven't been scheduled for interview yet but I'm aware that there's a technical test (for external candidates) involving manipulating CSV data and building maps etc. Apparently even internal candidates will have to take the test.

It's worth pointing out here that my day-to-day coding responsibilities will be the same: CSS/JS/HTML (although with some specialisms, I'll concede, around graphics-related stuff).

Part of me feels like I shouldn't have to do this – if the company wants to validate my technical capabilities surely they can look at the 4+ years of Github commits I've authored (for production code, too, not just interview scenarios). I'm not keen on having to "prove" myself again after already being an established member of the department. Should I push back on this or am I being unreasonable?

Comment: are you scheduled for this test? you sound like you're just *assuming* you will be tested...

Answer (score 10):

HR is probably making sure internal and external candidates are evaluated identically.

Also, it *IS* unreasonable to expect the company to assign someone to research your GitHub activity.

If it's a requirement to do the test to apply for the job, then you have to do the test.